# BUGZILLA - How to edit Assigned To list?

Tags: bug-tracking, bugzilla

It is possible to define in bugzilla the own list with assgined to users? In out company we have a lot of customers but when the customer assigned to one product he visible on all products on "assigned to" field. Can I change my assigned to select?

Answer (score 2):

Look at Security Groups - http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.2/en/html/groups.html

Then navigate to the group security page.
Administration -> Parameters -> Group Security

Find the setting makeproductgroups and ensure that is is On.

Next find the usevisibilitygroups setting and ensure that it is On. This setting prevents someone in group A from seeing the people in group B. This is especially important if you are letting multiple clients view and/or edit their bugs.

Finally find the strict_isolation setting and ensure it is On.

Now create your groups and assign them to products and users.